# What's the recommended way to create Alerts for Web Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, alert, monitor

We're looking into implementing alerts (5xx errors, high CPU usage etc.) for all our Web Apps.

In that case, we want to find the best/recommended way to do it.

As far as I know, this can be done via Application insights, Classic alerts on the Service Plan or Log Analytics.

But what would you go for?

Cheers.

Comment: Hello, suggesting you to check this link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-unified-alerts

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend including these in your templates or build process.

I used standard azure for this with an integration into Slack, but Application Insights is great to use. My process for creating these was based of the document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-create-metric-alerts-with-templates

And using the PowerShell call below to get the available metrics for a resource:

```
$resourceId = "makemearesourceid"

$count = Get-AzureRmMetricDefinition -ResourceId $resourceId

$i = 0

foreach($item in $count){

    $name = $count[$i].Name.Value

    $obj = New-Object psobject | select Name, Unit
    $obj.Name = $name
    $obj.Unit = $item.Unit

    [array]$output += $obj

    $i++
}

$output
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no best practices when it comes to alerts in Azure since every application/system is kind of unique. I would recommend you to use Application Insight to monitor the application(exceptions, slow queries etc) and to set up alerts on all Azure Resources(App service plans, web apps, storage accounts and so on) to monitor the infrastructure itself. Start with qualified guesswork on which metrics and levels and establish a baseline over a couple of weeks.